# Twitter Stream iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-streaming-api

How do I stream Tweets from a user's timeline?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use [Twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).  The endpoint you're looking for is [`statuses/home_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline):

> Returns a collection of the most recent Tweets and retweets posted by the authenticating user and the users they follow. The home timeline is central to how most users interact with the Twitter service.

If you're looking to get up-and-running quickly, you'll want to setup [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) (`pod 'STTwitter'` in your Cocoapods file).  STTwitter's Github page has a variety of tools for installation, authentication, configuration, etc.  You can use your own oauth token and secret (although you'd ideally want to avoid storing this in your app), or the authentication through iOS, although this does have a few limits.

Comment: Thank you very much, however, I have used STTwitter before and it seems like their rate limits are very small.

Comment: STTwitter doesn't have rate limits; Twitter's API does.  You can read about them here so you can code to avoid hitting them: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

Comment: Ok then! Great! I was wrong, thanks for helpin me out, do you know of a place with a nice tutorial on STTwitter? If you do not, no problem. You have been very helpful thanks

Comment: Googling "STTwitter Tutorial" produced this: http://tutorials.veasoftware.com/2013/12/23/twitter-api-version-1-1-app-authentication/